# Serverless Error code 10021: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack, cloudflare, serverless-framework, cloudflare-workers

I've been stuck for a while trying to deploy the template cloudflare worker with any package. I've been tinkering around with webpack for the past several hours with no luck. Without the require statement, deploying it and invoking the function works fine.

index.js

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

const _ = require('lodash');

async function handleRequest(request) {
  return new Response("Hello world")
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  optimization: { minimize: false },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: 'dist',
    filename: "main.js"
  },
  target: 'webworker',
};
```

Running this command seems to work too

curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/:zoneId/workers/script" -H "X-Auth-Email:CLOUDFLARE_AUTH_EMAIL" -H "X-Auth-Key:CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY" -H "Content-Type:application/javascript" --data-binary "@./dist/main.js"

The result is a huge blob of text followed by :

```
"success": true,
"errors": [],
"messages": []
```

I don't know why I can't seem to require any libraries, can someone please enlighten me?

Forgot to also say that invoking the function with the lodash also works.

Comment: How are you doing the webpack and deploy? Is this with serverless? What does your serverless.yml look like?

Answer (score 0):

add at the beginning

```
 target: 'webworker',
```

Remove those two lines

```
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
optimization: { minimize: false },
```

and run on production mode

Comment: Please provide an explanation.

Comment: CF workers takes only one file.
so the map file will not needed.